# Issus Ionic Cordova platform add IOS

Tags: ionic-framework

ionic Cordova platform and IOS

```
✖ Cordova platform adds ios --save - failed!
[ERROR] Exception: Using Cordova-fetch for Cordova-ios@^4.4.0

Error: Failed to fetch platform `cordova-ios@^4.4.0`
Probably this is either a connection problem or platform spec is incorrect.
Check your connection and platform name/version/URL.
Error: npm: Command failed with exit code 254 Error output:
npm ERR! path 

/Users/zion/Desktop/RSSFeederApp/node_modules/node_modules/file:cordova-dist-dev/CB-11690/cordova-common-1.4.1.tgz

npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! errno -2
npm ERR! syscall stat
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 
'/Users/zion/Desktop/RSSFeederApp/node_modules/node_modules/file:cordova-dist-dev/CB-11690/cordova-common-1.4.1.tgz'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent 

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/zion/.npm/_logs/2017-08-31T07_48_01_154Z-debug.log
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is related to npm 5.3.0.

It is best to downgrade to 5.2.0 using `npm install -g npm@5.2.0`

Answer (score 1):

For us this is most commonly caused by `npm`'s broken lockfile approach.

To resolve it, delete the `package-lock.json` and run your command again.

Answer (score -1):

try this, and make sure you are using Mac

```
ionic platform add ios
```